# Relocation Error after updating Ubuntu Mate

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-mate

I recently gave system update. After restarting the machine, I can't be able to open the terminal, network settings and any of my applications. The internet connectivity seems lost too.

It throws the following error if I try `sudo apt update` in XTerm.

> relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference

Have referred the internet and found no solution. Help me How to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem this morning on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 server and it messed up apache2 and apt. Found solution by downloading  [libidn2-0_2.0.5-1_amd64.deb](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.0.5-1_amd64.deb) and doing a dpkg -i (filename) this rolls back the effected file but makes things operational again. But if you apt upgrade after that, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks Warren. It fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad to help. have logged [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libidn2-0/+bug/1843559)